# A problem with javascript Range: deleteContents doesn't do anything at all

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a node from a contentEditable div, but nothing happens on `range.deleteContents()`:

```
var parseLine = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('Editor');
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    let text = $(selection.anchorNode)[0].data;
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
};
```

Upd.
The EditorName is a var with the id of the editor. For simplicity, I updated the code to use the name directly.
Here is the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">   
            <main data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl as HomeCtrl">
                <div id="Editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
            </main>
            <div id="PushFooter"></div> 
        </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/720fg8ne/

Expected behaviour would be: typing in text->pressing tab-> the text should disappear

Comment: Please include an example source HTML document and expected result.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Can you paste the html?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question and added the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Second line of your javascript code is wrong, editorName must be a string:

```
var el = document.getElementById('EditorName');
```

Text variable looks like a mix of vanilla js and jQuery, I fix it here:

```
let text = selection.anchorNode.data;
```

All code fixed:

```
var parseLine = function() {
var el = document.getElementById('EditorName');
var selection = window.getSelection();
let text = selection.anchorNode.data;

var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

range.deleteContents();

};
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough - I have now added a fiddle and html. EditorName was a variable - I've changed that to make it esiear to reproduce.